# Connecting signals in GTK+: anonymous way?

Tags: python, gtk

After reading ["Using your signals"](http://www.pygtk.org/articles/subclassing-gobject/sub-classing-gobject-in-python.htm) I am wondering if it is possible to connect the signals to "sinks" in an "anonymous" way?

In order words, if the example following (snippet from reference above):

```
aCar = Car()
aCar.connect('engine-started', myCallback)
```

Is it possible just to connect `myCallback` to all the signal `engine-started` sources in one go?  Something along the lines of:

`gbus.connect('engine-started', myCallback)`

Of course `gbus` here is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [gobject.add_emission_hook](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/gobject-functions.html#function-gobject--add-emission-hook) ([g_signal_add_emission_hook](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-add-emission-hook)).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088451/gobject-addemissionhook-usage